# How to fix 'choices must be an iterable' error in django models?

Tags: python, django-models

I'm trying  to migrate my app to the database, but the error does not allow me
Where I should make changes?

I have already looked through other Decisions. Nothing could help me

```py
class Movie(models.Model):                              
        NON_RATED = 0                                   
        RATED_G = 1                                     
        RATED_PG = 2                                    
        RATED_R = 3                                     
        RATINGS = (                                    
            (0, 'NR-not_rated'),                        
            (1, 'G-General_Audiences'),                 
            (2, 'PG-Parental_Guidances', 'Suggested'),  
            (3, 'R-Restricted')                         
        )          
        rating = models.IntegerField(     
                choices=RATINGS,            
                default=0)
```

Comment: can you please share the exact error ?

Comment: @AtulKumar kunar , it sounds like "(fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choices attribute takes a `list` or `tuple of 2 pairs`. You cannot have a **third** value as you have.

```
class Movie(models.Model):                              
        NON_RATED = 0                                   
        RATED_G = 1                                     
        RATED_PG = 2                                    
        RATED_R = 3                                     
        RATINGS = (                                    
            (0, 'NR-not_rated'),                        
            (1, 'G-General_Audiences'),                 
            (2, 'PG-Parental_Guidances', 'Suggested'),  # you should remove Suggested here. 
            (3, 'R-Restricted')                         
        )          
        rating = models.IntegerField(     
                choices=RATINGS,            
                default=0)
```

If you want another one you can try `(2, ('PG-Parental_Guidances', 'Suggested'))` but this will also give an error in some default values because of the internal structure.